# SQL: How to select rows that sum up to certain value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I want to select rows that sum up to a certain value.

My SQL ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaed9/9)):

```
id  user_id     storage
1   1           1983349
2   1           42552
3   1           367225
4   1           1357899
37  1           9314493
```

It should calculate the sum up to 410000 and get the rows. Meanwhile it should get something like this:

```
id  user_id     storage
2   1           42552
3   1           367225
```

As you can see, 42552 + 367225 = 409777. It selected two rows that are nearly 410000.

I have tried everything but it didn't work :(

Sorry for my language, I am German.

Comment: with php that would be trivial You want a mysql only solution?

Comment: It seems like you are relatively new to StackOverflow. If an answer helped you, be sure to vote it up. If it solved your problem, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @GeorgePant No, PHP would be better :)

Comment: This looks like something better solved with dynamic programming or backtracking.

Comment: `I have tried everything but it didn't work :(` I am not sure, really everything? Should one believe this? :D Never mind plz have a look at http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/. Rather than telling, everyone is expected to show (the code) what has been tried

Comment: Question is not any clear yet. So you want to ignore all those rows where `storage>410000` and fetch all those rows that are less than `410000`. No? something else?? then please add more sample data (more rows lesser than 410000) and then the whole expected result, It might get bit clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the running total and retrieve those rows whose running total is < a specified number. (note that i changed the storage column to `int`. if it is a `varchar` the comparison would return the wrong result)

```
select id,user_id,storage
from uploads t
where storage+coalesce((select sum(storage) from uploads 
                        where storage<t.storage),0) < 410000
order by storage
```

[**`SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17bcc3/4)

Edit: When there are duplicate values in the storage column, it has to be accounted for in the running sum by including a condition for the `id` column. (in this case `<` condition has been used, so the smallest id for a duplicate storage value gets picked up)

```
select id,user_id,storage
from uploads t
where storage+coalesce((select sum(storage) from uploads 
                        where storage<t.storage 
                        or (storage=t.storage and id < t.id)),0) < 410000
order by storage
```

Comment: you need to pick only one of those rows when they have equal values. Use a `group by` on user_id and storage in that case. However, this would be a problem in other cases too..i will fix it.

Comment: look at the edited version which doesn't require a `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
SET @suma = 0;
SELECT @suma:=@suma+`storage`, id, storage FROM table 
WHERE @suma<=410000 
ORDER BY storage ASC;
```

I added "ORDER BY storage ASC" to skip rows that have to much storage.